# sending js variables to php page - not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

This is what my javascript looks like:

```
print "<script>function newpage(){

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

var PageToSendTo = 'select_db.php?';
var MyVariable = 'variableData';
var VariablePlaceholder = 'variableName=';
var UrlToSend = PageToSendTo + VariablePlaceholder + MyVariable + '&tweet_id='" .     $id_num;

print "xmlhttp.open('GET', UrlToSend);
xmlhttp.send();
}</script>";
```

(it is in a php file hence the print statement)

This is what my form submission looks like: (again in a php statement)

```
print "<form action=\"select_db.php\" onSubmit=\"return newpage()\">";
```

The function newpage is not working.. I expected the variables to be sent over in the URL but the resulting URL is just select_db.php?

help, please.

Comment: Your code has "VariablePlaceholder" twice ... is the second one supposed to be "MyVariable"? It's still not really a valid query string.

Comment: changed it.. still not working

Comment: You should use the browser console to inspect the http request and see how it's being sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the initial `<script>` tag...

```
print "<script>function newpage(){

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

var PageToSendTo = 'select_db.php?';
var MyVariable = 'variableData';
var VariablePlaceholder = 'variableName=';
var UrlToSend = PageToSendTo + VariablePlaceholder + VariablePlaceholder + '$tweet_id='" .     $id_num;

print "xmlhttp.open('GET', UrlToSend);
xmlhttp.send();
}</script>";
```

does that solve your problem ?

Comment: It's there, just didn't include it in the code.. will edit now.

Comment: Can you say `return true;` as last line in your function and try ?

Answer (score 0):

try this `onSubmit=\"newpage(); return false; \"`

Comment: It won't work to return `false` *before* calling the function, because the function will thus never be called.

Comment: @Pointy was right; I've update the solution: place function before return